# Photo doesn't upload because yet in db, how to overwrite?

Tags: java

I am new to Java, but the back of the web app I am coding is in Java and no one in my team can help me.

My problem: In the user profile component, I have an input to edit the photo but every time it returns an error message.

It seems it's because file already exists in the database, so the photo is never updated.

I think there is something wrong or missing **in the back side** .

### FRONT (angular)

**expert-profile.component.html**

```js
<!-- [...] -->
<!-----------------------------------------
    img profile
  -------------------------------------------->
  <div
    class="profileImg"
    [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + photoUrl + ')' }"
    *ngIf="this.userInfos"
  >
   <!-- upload or change profile photo -->
    <input
      type="file"
      accept="image/*"
      style="display: none;"
      #file
      (change)="changeProfilePhoto($event.target.files)"
    />

    <mat-icon
      class="editIcon"
      *ngIf="ownProfile"
      (click)="file.click()"
      matTooltip="Only .png or .jpg/.jpeg img with min-size: Ko and max-size: Ko"
    >
      edit
    </mat-icon>
  </div>
<!-- [...] -->
```

**expert-profile.component.ts**

```js
// imports...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-expert-profile',
  templateUrl: './expert-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./expert-profile.component.less'],
})

export class ExpertProfileComponent implements OnInit {

//[...]

async changeProfilePhoto(file: FileList) {
    console.log(' async changeProfilePhoto....', file);
    console.log('---------------------REQUEST------------------------------');
    this.fileService
      .uploadProfilePhoto(file[0], this.profileId)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log('changeProfilePhoto (res)', res); // test res= null
        if (res == null) {
          this.snackbar.open('Error (to handle) : File already uploaded', '', {
            duration: 2500,
          });
        } else {
          console.log('loading ok');
          location.reload();
        }
      });
    console.log('------------------------ END ---------------------------');
  }
}
```

*console.log return--->*

```
[...]
------------------------ END ---------------------------
changeProfilePhoto (res) null
```

*browser return --->*
a snackbar with message:

> Error (to handle) : File already uploaded

Photo is uploaded but not used.

### Back End

**FileUploadController.java**

```java
/* uploadprofilephoto #1 */
    @PostMapping("/user/{userId}/avatar")
    public ResponseEntity<UserInfo> uploadProfilePhoto(@PathVariable UUID userId, @RequestParam MultipartFile avatar,
                                                  HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("............................................................................");
        System.out.println("                       uploadprofilephoto #1    ");
            System.out.println("............................................................................");                                          
        try {
            System.out.println("............................     TRY     ......................................");
           
            UserInfo u = storageService.addUserAvatar(userId, avatar.getOriginalFilename(), avatar.getInputStream());
            URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{userId}").buildAndExpand("").toUri();
            return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(u);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(".......................................   CATCH: (e below)   .....................................");
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("............................................................................");
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
        }
        
    }
```

**addUserAvatar() in FileStorageService.java**

```java
  /* #uploadprofilephoto #2*/
    public UserInfo addUserAvatar(UUID userId, String filename, InputStream fileContent) {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------- ");
        System.out.println("                        #2 - change my profile img by    "+filename);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------- ");
        UserEntity user = userServiceActions.findById(userId);

        //If fileId in userProfile is already present in filedatabase , it delete it in filedatabase + directory
        //#3
        try {
            this.delete(user.getImage());
        } catch(Exception e) {}

        //create path for a new avatar + directory to store it
        Path directory = router.getOrCreatePathFromFilename(userId, filename, "avatar");
        Path location = fileSaver.store(filename, fileContent, directory);

        //request for a new file
        var f = new FileRequest();
        f.filename = filename;
        f.projectId = Optional.of(userId);
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType(getContentType(location));
       
        //Create an entity for this file with a uniq Id, and add it in file db
        //#4 + #5
        FileEntity fileEntity = fileServiceActions.add(UUID.randomUUID(), mediaType.getType(), mediaType.getSubtype(), f , "avatar");
        
        //update the imageId in user db with the new one
        //#6
        user.setImage(fileEntity.getId());
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------- ");
        System.out.println("                        #6 - CrudRepository save in user the new imageId:   "+user.getImage());
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------- ");
        userRepository.save(user);//seems to block if a photo was allready uploaded by past with the same filename
       
        //return the new data and update profile
        UserInfo userInfo = mapper.map(user, UserInfo.class);
        return userInfo;
    }
```

(see return of console print below)

**delete() in FileStorageService.java** (everything seems ok)

```
 /* #uploadprofilephoto #3*/
    public void delete(UUID id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------- ");
        System.out.println("                        #3 - delete    "+id);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------- ");
        FileEntity file = fileServiceActions.findById(id);
         Path directory = router.getOrCreatePathFromFilename(file.getProjectId(), file.getFilename(), file.getCategory());
        
        fileSaver.deleteFromDisk(directory, file.getFilename());
        
        fileServiceActions.delete(id);
        System.out.println("end delete ---------------------------------------------------- ");
    }
```

**add() & save() in FileServiceActions.java** (Pb comes from the save according to me )

```java
  /**
     * #uploadprofilephoto #4
     * Allows to give a pre-generated UUID to the file. Useful when we want to have the
     * UUID before adding a record to the database.
     */
    public FileEntity add(UUID fileId, String type, String subtype, FileRequest req , String category) {
        FileEntity fileEntity;
        
        try {
            ProjectEntity proj = null;
            proj = projectServiceActions.findById(req.projectId.orElseThrow());
            fileEntity = toEntity(proj.getId(), req, type, subtype, category);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            UserEntity user = null;
            user = userServiceActions.findById(req.projectId.orElseThrow());
            fileEntity = toEntity(user.getId(), req, type, subtype, category);
        }
        fileEntity.setId(fileId);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("                        #4 add this new file in file db    ");
        System.out.println(fileEntity);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        return save(fileEntity).orElseThrow();
    }

[...]

/**
     * #uploadprofilephoto #5
     * If any error happens, Optional.empty() is returned.
     */
    private Optional<FileEntity> save(FileEntity file) {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------- ");
        System.out.println("                        #5 - Save   ");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------- ");
        FileEntity savedUser = fileRepository.save(file);
        System.out.println("---->#5 : savedUser: "+savedUser);//pb is during the save, this consolePrint never be return when img allready exist in db
        return Optional.ofNullable(savedUser);
    }
```

**save() in CrudRepository.class** ('Pb' comes from this save according to me )

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {

    /**
     * Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the
     * entity instance completely.
     *
     * @param entity must not be {@literal null}.
     * @return the saved entity will never be {@literal null}.
     */
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);

[...]
}
```

### Terminal when it fails:

(look the 2)
[screenshot_1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFGTl.png)
[screenshot_1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LUuo.png)

### Terminal when it works:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1qj0.png)

Somebody have an idea How to resolve my problem?

I think the solution is
either:

- if fileName allready exist , just change the id by the newOne (or catch its id and use it for the imageId in user db)
  or:
  -if fileName allready exist , delete it and save the newOne

What do you think about this solution?
How to code it in Java?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I can't upload a photo that I have already used once and which is therefore already listed in the database. That return to the request in the front an error message.

Comment: Well, having a database unicity constraint on user generated data can not work. Here, the filename (which is based on the name of a file on some user's computer) should not be used as a uniquely indentifiable data. **Of course** it is only a matter of time before another user (or a malicious one) uses the same name as some other user. You have to do differently. It would probably be a major failure for profile pictures from one user to overwrite that of another one. So : generate a unique file name/identifier for each upload process, and discard (as an identifier) the actual file's name.

Comment: If a user upload a file named 'myAvatar.jpeg', while an other user has a photo also named  'myAvatar.jpeg' will not be a pb, because program check the fileName according to the userId. It doesn't work only if the user have allready a file with the same name. On the other hand, I didn't write this code so I can't change the fact that the original name is kept...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my pb.
According to the update of the specifications, I keep in db and directory only one img/avatar for each user.

So I have changed the delete(user.imageId) by deleteAllByUserIdAndCategory(user.id, 'avatar').